# Delphi & SQL code adding

Tags: sql, delphi

Is there a chance to edit the SQL code without erasing it?
I Need the Query for much more tables and fields, and i can't add them all in the code it is more then 800 symbols

And this is much as i know about delphi whit sql:

```
  Form4.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  Form4.ADOQuery1.SQL.ADD('SELECT * FROM SKTech WHERE  SKtech.Tech='+#39+ComboBox1.Text+#39+';');
  Form4.ADOQuery1.Active := true;
```

As you can see i'm using sql whit combobox to chose different fields to show. This code works perfectly, but i can't add all my tables & fields...
Is only way to do this is to store all the query in multiple strings?

Comment: ADO can return multiple recordsets by a single command execution (don't know if `TADOQuery` component though). However, the question is how comfortable will this be for you.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. SQL is simply text, so you can *edit SQL code without erasing it* all you want, in any way you want. I'd strongly suggest that you do a search on `[delphi] sql parameters` here, which will make your life much easier (and your code much more secure.

Comment: Do you know that you don't have to use the designtime components and that you can create your queries on the fly at runtime? And please do not use [sql injection vulnerable queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and learn how to use [parametrized queries](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/ADOQuery_(Delphi)).

Comment: Just small suggestion, instead of '+#39+ComboBox1.Text+#39+' use function QuotedStr()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For short queries I usually use a TStringList, that I can parse using a loop (or TStringList.IndexOf for a full string match) to locate "FROM", "WHERE" and other SQL tokens. Then I can insert new fields or conditions at the right place.

For longer queries (hundreds of lines) I sometimes use a TQueryBuilder class, based on the same principle but where query tokens are splitted:

```
TQueryBuilder = class
private
  FSelect: TStrings;
  FFrom: TStrings;
  FWhere: TStrings;
  FOrderBy: TStrings;
  ...
public
  function GetQuery: TStrings;
```

Then:

```
myDataset.SQL := myQueryBuilder.GetQuery;
```